# Swap position of words in an array of 2-word elements

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, swap, cpu-word

We have array with names:

```
[
    'Robin Hood',
    'Little John',
    'Maid Marion',
    'Friar Tuck',
    'Will Scarlet'
]
```

First word inside each item should be moved to the end of this item.

We should get this:

```
[
    'Hood Robin',
    'John Little',
    'Marion Maid',
    'Tuck Friar',
    'Scarlet Will'
]
```

Comment: What about `Butros Butros Ghali` or `Hillary Rodham Clinton` or `Carl Gustav Jung`? The former two have a two-part last name, the latter one a two-part first name

Comment: please clarify if you are after First word or First name. If after first name, please clarify how to approach the problem Pekka pointed out above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*If* you only need to move the part before the first whitespace (setting `$limit = 2` in [`explode()`](https://www.php.net/explode) to get two parts only):

```
function func($n) {
        list($first, $rest) = explode(' ', $n, 2);
        return $rest . ' ' . $first;
} 
$trans = array_map('func', $names);
```

([Demo](http://www.ideone.com/sDIiO))

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hood Robin
    [1] => John Little
    [2] => Marion Maid
    [3] => Tuck Friar
    [4] => Scarlet Will
    [5] => Fitzgerald Kennedy John
)
```

Comment: As of PHP 5.3 you can use lambda functions for [callback functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Answer (score 3):

Not a particularly glamorous solution:

```
foreach( $person_array as $key => $value){

$reversed_person_array[]=implode(' ', array_reverse(explode(' ', $value,2)));

}
```

Comment: You should use `explode(' ', $value, 2)`.

Comment: note that reversing the array won't give the described result (first elemt to the end) for names sonsisting of more than 2 parts.

Comment: And the foreach needs an `as`.

Comment: @Gumbo, shamittomar, +1 & +1 Edited, thanks for that, I wrote a little too quickly there!

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($names as $key => $name)
{
    $splitted = explode(' ', $name, 2);
    $names[$key] = $splitted[1].' '.$splitted[0];
}
```

Comment: You should use `explode(' ', $name, 2)`.

Comment: note: for names with more than 2 parts, you'll miss everything after the second. use explode with limit 2 please.

Answer (score 1):

walk through you array, use [explode](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) to split the entry at ' '(space), then use [array_shift](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.array-shift.php) to cut of and get the first element, [array_push](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.array-push.php) it to the end and [implode](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) the whole thing again with ' '(space).

Answer (score 0):

Ha! that's great Ahmet!

I was working on something similar... got to

```
$first = $array[0];
array_shift($array);
array_push($array, $first);
```

then I refreshed the page and saw yours. Clean and neat!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform any iterated function calls or processes, just use `preg_replace()` on the input array, capture the words individually, then swap them in the replacement string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/l63Qv))

```
var_export(
    preg_replace('/(\S+) (\S+)/', '$2 $1', $array)
);
```